# Is "implicit overloading" possible?

Tags: types, f#, arguments, overloading, implicit

I've got the following example:

```
type Stream (capacity) =
    let data = Array.zeroCreate capacity
    member private s.position = ref 0
    static member private encoder = new Text.UTF8Encoding()
    static member private write (x, o, a : byte[]) = for i = 0 to 3 do a.[o + i] <- byte((x >>> 24 - i * 8) % 256)
    static member private write (x, o, a : byte[]) = for i = 0 to 1 do a.[o + i] <- byte((x >>> 24 - i * 8) % 256s)
    static member private write (x : string, o : int, a : byte[]) = Stream.encoder.GetBytes(x, 0, x.Length, a, o)
    static member format (x : int, s) = let a = Array.create s 0uy in Stream.write(x, 0, a); a
    static member format (x : int16, s) = let a = Array.create s 0uy in Stream.write(x, 0, a); a
    static member format (x : string, s) = let a = Array.create s 0uy in Stream.write(x, 0, a); a
```

First of all, sorry for the terribly messy code, I'm only a beginner in F#. As you may see the three `format` overloads differ only for their argument type, while their body is the same (although calling different overloads of `write`). Is it possible somehow to reduce the format functions to one, maybe inlined?

I apologize in case I'm completely missing the point here, but I couldn't find much information about the matter.

Comment: This seems like [pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx) might be a better fit.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without boxing x?

Comment: That's a good question... The way you've written this looks more like an OO program than a functional one.

Comment: T0yv0 here uses a dictionary of types storing the serializing functions, but he definitely have one serializing function per type: https://gist.github.com/1082622

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the way you wrote it is probably the best option.

If you don't want to do boxing, then the overloaded `write` function is definitely needed, because the serialization needs to be implemented differently for different types. Using `inline` member also doesn't work in this case, because `inline` function can only require a specific instance or static method *on* some value it gets, but not a specific overload.

A reasonable solution that avoids some duplication is to define just a single overloaded function (i.e. `write`) and then pass it explicitly as an argument to other functions if they need it. You could write something like:

```
type Stream (capacity) = 
    let data = Array.zeroCreate capacity 
    member private s.position = ref 0 
    static member private encoder = new Text.UTF8Encoding() 
    static member Write (x, o, a : byte[]) = 
        for i = 0 to 3 do a.[o + i] <- byte((x >>> 24 - i * 8) % 256) 
    static member Write (x, o, a : byte[]) = 
        for i = 0 to 1 do a.[o + i] <- byte((x >>> 24 - i * 8) % 256s) 
    static member Write (x : string, o : int, a : byte[]) = 
        Stream.encoder.GetBytes(x, 0, x.Length, a, o) |> ignore
    // Format takes a writer function 'f' as the first argument
    static member Format (x, s) f = let a = Array.create s 0uy in f(x, 0, a); a 

// When you call 'Format' with 'Stream.Write' as an argument, 
// the compiler chooses the right overload for you
Stream.Format (1s, 100) Stream.Write 
Stream.Format ("foo", 100) Stream.Write
```

This avoids some code duplication at the definition side, but it makes the usage longer. If you don't need many functions like `Format`, then the best way may be to define an overload with some code duplication as you did originally.

Regarding `inline`, you can use that to specify that a type of the argument should implement some specific member (either instance or static), but you cannot say that there should be a specific overload. If you wrote wrappers for all three types (`int16`, `string`, ...) that had a static member `Write`, then you could write:

```
let inline format< ^T when ^T : 
    (static member Write : ^T * int * byte[] -> unit)> (value:^T) size =
  let a = Array.create size 0uy
  (^T : (static member Write : ^T * int * byte[] -> unit) (value, 0, a)) 
  a
```

... but that's even more complex solution that also requires writing some additional code when calling `format`, so I wouldn't really use that approach (but it may be useful to know that it exists).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the alternative way suggested!

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring `format` functions is obvious; you can create a generic format function and pass different `Stream.write` functions as parameters. First, put the generic function before any member of the class:

```
    static let formatGeneric writeFunc x s =
           let a = Array.create s 0uy         
           writeFunc(x, 0, a)         
           a
```

and using it to instantiate different format functions:

```
    static member format (x, s) = 
           formatGeneric (fun (x: int, i, a) -> Stream.write(x, i, a)) x s
    static member format (x, s) = 
           formatGeneric (fun (x: int16, i, a) -> Stream.write(x, i, a)) x s
    static member format (x, s) = 
           formatGeneric (fun (x: string, i, a) -> Stream.write(x, i, a)) x s
```

Notice that `Stream.write` is written in the full form and type of `x` is annotated to select a suitable overload.